# Approximation to any real number by rationals

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given a real number $x$, one can show that there exists infinitely many $p,q$, such that $\gcd(p,q)=1$, and $|x-\frac{p}{q}|\leq \frac{1}{q^2}$. (There is a hint saying that I should use the pigeon hole principle, but how?)

And that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there are only finitely many $p,q$, such that $\gcd(p,q)=1$, and $|x-\frac{p}{q}|\leq \frac{1}{q^{2+\varepsilon}}$

I am very confused by this problem, can anyone help me with it? Thanks.

Comment: [This](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lyonsc/Math_Club_talk_Feb2011.pdf) is a good read. See Section 2. for your first problem.

Comment: Thanks, it explains why the first part holds.But what about the second part? @David Mitra

Comment: you need x algebraic

Comment: Actually, x algebraic is a sufficient but not a necessary condition for $2^{nd}$ part to be true, there are transcedental number like $e$ whose [irrationality measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) is $2$ which is equivalent to $2^{nd}$ part works for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are asking about one of the the basic problems of **Diophantine Approximation**, which is an important subfield of number theory.  (Thus I disagree with Christian Blatter's answer that these are isolated results, although I suppose this depends a lot on how you want to group results together and gerrymander various subfields of mathematics.)  Other results in this area include the Siegel-Mahler S-Unit Theorem and Siegel's Big Theorem on S-integral points on algebraic curves.

Both of your claims are false as stated: there are missing hypotheses.

Your first claim fails for rational numbers: if $x$ is rational, there is one excellent rational approximation -- namely, take $\frac{p}{q} = x$ -- but one cannot find *infinitely many* distinct rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}$ such that $|x-\frac{p}{q}| \leq \frac{1}{q^2}$.  In fact, we cannot do this with $\frac{1}{q^2}$ replaced by $\frac{1}{q^{1+\epsilon}}$ for any positive $\epsilon$.

However the result is true if $x$ is irrational.  The proof is extremely elementary and uses no more than the Pigeonhole Principle.  In fact *this* is the result for which the Pigeonhole Principle was first explicitly identified as a useful proof technique.  Note that in certain circles PHP is also called "Dirichlet's Box Principle" or "Dirichlet's Schubfachprinzip" (which apparently has something to do with "drawers").

Your second claim fails for infinitely many real numbers.  In fact,
there are (uncountably) infinitely many real numbers $x$ such that for any fixed $d$, no matter how large, there are infinitely many coprime integers $p,q$ with $|x-\frac{p}{q}| \leq \frac{1}{q^d}$.  The standard example is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 10^{-n!}$.

I suppose that what you have in mind is a celebrated [theorem of Klaus Roth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Siegel%E2%80%93Roth_theorem) from the 1950's.   What Roth proved -- greatly improving on previous results of Liouville, Thue, Siegel, Gelfond and Dyson -- is that this holds for all **real algebraic** numbers.

I give an introduction to this circle of ideas in $\S$ 14 of [these lecture notes on elliptic curves](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/EllipticCurves.pdf).  Early on I include a proof of Dirichlet's Theorem together with some classical number theoretic applications: Pell's Equation.  I *do not* prove Roth's Theorem, although I state and use an even stronger theorem of Roth-Ridout.  For a detailed proof of Roth-Ridout I recommend the GTM *Diophantine Geometry* by Hindry and Silverman.

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, but there was also an proposition that the set of x which satisfies that there are infinitely many coprime p,q such that $|x-p/q|\leq 1/q^{2}$ has measure 0. Does it have anything to do with the fact that x must be algebraic?@Pete L. Clark

Comment: I don't understand your question.  As mentioned in my answer, the set of $x$ satisfying your inequality is all irrational numbers, so it has full measure.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks Pete!

Answer (score 4):

I think the first is comparatively easy, but the second refers to one of the landmark theorems of $20^{\rm th}$ century mathematics, the so-called [*Thue-Siegel-Roth theorem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%2DSiegel%2DRoth%5Ftheorem). Roth got a Fields medal for it. It's still a "solitaire" theorem; it has not become part of a larger theory. Note that the statement only holds for algebraic numbers. The number
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty 10^{-k!}=0.11000100000000000000000100\ldots$$
(or similar) has infinitely many approximations of the described kind.